# Difference between LFM and adaptive throttling for TM2 thermal management

Tags: bios, supermicro

Some Supermicro BIOS have a 'TM2 Mode' option under Advanced/CPU configuration. Available values are:

- LFM throttling
- adaptive throttling

What are the differences between those two throttling modes? What are the advantages/disadvantage with respect to performance/latency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LFM stands for "low frequency mode", which is contrast to HFM or "high frequency mode".

The "TM2 mode" available on Supermicro and other BIOSes define what the CPU should do when overheating (ie: engaging TM2, generally when temp >= 90C):

- LFM throttling will immediately put the CPU into reduced performance mode (eg: 800 Mhz, but this is SKU/version specific);
- adaptive throttling, where the CPU dynamically throttles itself based on the current temp/load, modulating its clock but without immediately dropping to a pre-defined low frequency mode.

You can read more [here](https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/88518/?page=110)